# json parsing error in reactjs application

Tags: reactjs

Hi am I creating dynamic html using json object but getting errror

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, fee, gst, formid, form, no_of_tickets}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

My function is as follows :

```
getForms(categoreis,id1){
      var ind=0;
      var list1=[];
      var list2=[];
      console.log(JSON.stringify(categoreis));
    categoreis.map(function(category,index){
        if(category.hasOwnProperty('no_of_tickets')){
          if(ind==0){
            list1.push(<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href={"#"+index+"3"}>{category.name}</a></li>);
            ind=ind+1;

          }else{
            list1.push(<li><a data-toggle="tab" href={"#"+index+"3"}>{category.name}</a></li>);
            list2.push(<div id={index+"3"} class="tab-pane fade in active">
              {category.name}
            </div>
            );
          }
        }
      }
      )

      return
      <div id={id1} class="tab-pane fade" >
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
           {list1}
         </ul>
         <div class="tab-content">
            {list2}
         </div>
       </div>;
  }
```

JSON is as follows as printed by console.log is

```
[{"name":"Men Singles","fee":"600","gst":"108","formid":102,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"}],"no_of_tickets":1},{"name":"Men Singles 35+","fee":"600","gst":"108","formid":108,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"}]},{"name":"Men Doubles","fee":"1200","gst":"216","formid":103,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"},{"label":"Partner Name:","paramname":"partner_name","type":"text"},{"label":"Partner Email:","paramname":"partner_email","type":"text"}]},{"name":"Men Doubles 35+","fee":"1200","gst":"216","formid":109,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"},{"label":"Partner Name:","paramname":"partner_name","type":"text"},{"label":"Partner Email:","paramname":"partner_email","type":"text"}]},{"name":"Women Doubles","fee":"1200","gst":"216","formid":104,"form":[{"label":"Name:","paramname":"name","type":"text"},{"label":"Email:","paramname":"email","type":"text"},{"label":"Phone:","paramname":"phone","type":"text"},{"label":"Partner Name:","paramname":"partner_name","type":"text"},{"label":"Partner Email:","paramname":"partner_email","type":"text"}]}]
```

Comment: Please share more code with proper usage. What is `getForms()` ? Why is it returning JSX?

Comment: I Run your code, its work, can you share all your component code?

Comment: It seems like you use raw categories array in JSX code.

Comment: I have this error in next case: 
var a = {a: 1, b: 2}
render:
<div>{a}</div>

In such case I have error same as you.